# Xyplex MaxServer 20 Terminal Server

Tags: terminal, console, serial-port, memory-card, tftp

I recently purchased a Xyplex (which was purchased by MRV) MaxServer 1620 terminal server for my CCNA lab so I could manage all of the console connections from a single device..  Well, that was the idea at least.

When I received the terminal server, it did not have any memory card installed in it.   I contacted the person I purchased the terminal server from and he told me I could boot the device via PXE/TFTP if I had the software for the terminal server.   Unfortunatley, the person who sold me the device does not have the software for this device.  I can't seem to find a download when I google for it, so I was hoping someone here on SuperUser might have some experience with MRV/Xplex terminal servers and could possibly point me towards a place where i can download the software so I can at least boot the damn thing.

I do plan on buying a memory card for the unit, but if I cannot find the software for the device what is the point?   The memory card it uses is this strange PCMCIA 2MB flash memory that costs like $50 for 2-4MB.   Yes, I said $50 for 2-4 MEGABYTES..   sigh...
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you already find this thread.... I don't see much about software but perhaps you'll see something that may take you down this right path otherwise from some of the links and read, etc. http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/General/Xyplex-MaxServer-MX-1620-Terminal-Server-boot-issues/td-p/5183921?notmigrated#.Vir9_NKrTGg

Comment: https://www.pcliquidations.com/p1473-xyplex-maxserver-20-terminal#   you might check out this site with some contact information and see if they sell just the software or disk or whatever it takes to load its OS.  Also, I think this is a `MaxServer 20 Terminal Server` rather than your title suggests of `MaxServer 1620 Terminal Server`. Not sure if you've looked on ebay or other selling sites, etc. perhaps you could find another whole device cheap that comes with what you need.  Good Luck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already find this thread.... I don't see much about software but perhaps you'll see something that may take you down this right path otherwise from some of the links and read, etc.

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/General/Xyplex-MaxServer-MX-1620-Terminal-Server-boot-issues/td-p/5183921?notmigrated#.Vi1wC9KrTGh